# vue js jest.spyOn mounted function call not working in unit test on class component

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js

I am new to unit testing and I am trying to test a function being called when the component is mounted. Below is the component code I am testing:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="grid">
      <Card
        class="grid_layout_col"
        @showItemDetail="showDetails(index)"
        @openEditModal="editItem(index)"
      />
    </div>
    <!-- fab -->
    <Fab ref="fabBtn" @addItem="showModal" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
// @ is an alias to /src
import { Component, Prop, Vue, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";
import router from "../router";
import { store, actions, mutations } from "@/store/store";
import Card from "@/components/Card.vue";
import Fab from "@/components/Fab.vue";

@Component({
  components: {
    Card,
    Fab
  }
})
export default class Home extends Vue {
  itemData: Array<object>;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.itemData = [];
  }

  convertBlobURL(imageData: string) {}

  showDetails(val: number) {}

  addItem() {}

  editItem(val: string) {}

  showModal() {}

  resetHeader() {}

   mounted() {
    // load the card data
    actions.loadData();

  }
}
```

Here is the code for the actions:

```
 export const actions = {
  loadData(){
    store.loadData();
  },
  getDelStoreLength(): number {
    return store.delStore.length;
  },
  getStoreLength(): number {
    return store.dataStore.data.length; 
  }
};
```

The problem I am facing is when I run the jest test below:

```
import { shallowMount, mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Home from "@/views/Home.vue";

//
const factory = (propsData: object) => {
  return shallowMount(Home, {
    propsData: {
      ...propsData
    },
    stubs: {

    },
    mocks: {

    }
  });
};
it("should call actions.loadData function on mounted", () => {
  const wrapper = factory({});
  let spyIt = jest.spyOn(Home as any, 'actions.loadData');
  expect(spyIt).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I get the below:

**Cannot spy the actions.loadData property because it is not a function; undefined given instead**

Does anyone know what this is and how to fix it?

Comment: `actions.loadData` isn't a property of `Home`. You're trying to mock an external import, so you're going to have something like `jest.mock("@/store/store")`; see e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already noted, `actions` isn't a property of `Home` component, so it cannot be spied on it. Even if it were, it couldn't be spied as `jest.spyOn(Home as any, 'actions.loadData')` because component properties aren't exposed on component object itself and it's incorrect to refer to nested properties with 'actions.loadData' string.

It should be:

```
import { actions } from "@/store/store";
  ...
  let spyIt = jest.spyOn(actions, 'loadData').mockImplementation(() => {});
  // mount Home
  expect(spyIt).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Thanks Estus Flask that worked perfectly and thanks for the explanation. I get it now.